# Audio spectrum, use path for custom shape

Tags: adobe-after-effects

[image]

There's a place to choose a path in the Audio Spectrum effect menu (1) and I have created such a path (2), however when I try to choose it in (1) only "None" shows up. The Mask 1 is in a Null Object Layer. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer... The path needs to be on the same layer as the effect:

[image]